# Powershell (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile Strings como Argumentos

Tags: string, powershell, argumento, webclient

Tenho o seguinte código que utilizo para fazer download do último *chromedriver* para uma pasta específica:

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$($ChromeDriverLatestVersion)/chromedriver_win32.zip", "C:\path\Debug\chromedriver.zip")
```

em que `$ChromeDriverLatestVersion` é o número da última release. Este código funciona. No entanto se meter ambos os argumentos em strings, o segundo argumento gera uma excepção. Exemplo:

`(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("$Chrome", "$ZipChromePath")`

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form." ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NewNormalizePath(String path, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri(String path)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , String )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Sei que é o segundo argumento que causa a excepção, porque se mantiver o

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("$Chrome", "C:\path\Debug\chromedriver.zip")
```

o código corre. Simplesmente não consigo explicar porquê...

Answer (score 0):

Por algum motivo que não consegui visualizar, a minha string tinha caracteres inválidos. Foram removidos da seguinte forma.

```
$array=$array -replace "`n",""
```

e

```
$array=$array -replace "`r",""
```

Espero ter ajudado.